# Call update state function within a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to add an auto increment counter to a map function that would populate a question number on my component.

I am not sure how best to call this function within the map function I have in place and any help would be greatly appreciated. I would be looking to place the updated count in the Typography with "Open Question" output.

```
    const [questionCounter, setQuestionCounter] = useState(0)
```

```
    const updateCounter = (e) => {
        setQuestionCounter(questionCounter++)
      }
```

```
    {quiz.question.map((questions) => (
          <Card elevation={6}>
            <Grid>
              <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                >
                  <Typography>Open Question</Typography>
```

Comment: Do you really need the question counter state? You could use the index as the question counter. Add 1 into the index if you want to start from 1.

Comment: What purpose does the counter have? You already know how many questions there are: `quiz.question.length`.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didnt know the map function had an index that auto increments itself, managed to use the index plus 1 for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I am now using the index within the map function and adding 1 to the base when it starts so that each question has the correct number against it now in the accordion summary.

```
 <Typography className={classes.quizDescription}>{quiz.longDescription}</Typography>
        {quiz.question.map((questions, index) => (
          <Card elevation={6}>
            <Grid>
              <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                >
                  <Typography>Open Question {index + 1}</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
```